# Search for existence of a value other than query in array field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

How to filter out documents on a multi-value field (array) to select documents where exists a value which doesn't matches a request value.

Documents:

```
{ "name" : "Ahmed", "fruits": ["apple", "banana"] }
{ "name" : "Bryce", "fruits": [ "banana"] }
{ "name" : "Caitlin", "fruits": ["apple", "mango"] }
```

I want to filter all the names who have at least 1 fruit in `fruits` field, which is not `banana` So in this case, I want to get document 1 and document 3 (i.e. Ahmed and Caitlin)

Currently I've following query, but it would also filter out document1.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "fruit": "banana"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do it with your current mapping without using a script. Following script query should work.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": """doc['fruits'].value != params.param1 && doc['fruits'].length > 1""",
            "lang": "painless",
            "params": {
              "param1": "banana"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```